# Adding a label to points in a Bokeh graph automatically

Tags: python, pandas-bokeh

I want to add labels to certain points in a Bokeh graph, but I want to do it only via the x-value, without having to state the y-value. The illustration of the plot and the image is linked. [the points that I want to label exists in the beginning of each red tapes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvuUB.jpg)

I've tried labelling using the hover tool, but that's not what I had in mind. Is there any function to call a y value of certain x value? I imagine after finding that function, I will set the label to display it, for 4 red tape beginnings, and then it's just a matter of repeating the process of each files.

Thank you!